# Push notification on Samsung Galaxy Note (GT-I717)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, push-notifications

Why is there no push notification or some notification for incoming messages in the screen when the phone is in locked state? I am using Samsung Galaxy Note. When my phone is in locked state, and when I click the power button I see the pattern unlocking screen. When new messages flow in, I just see a mail icon in the top status bar, but no other notifications in the screen. What needs to be done for that?

Comment: What other notifications do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like something on your screen in addition to the notification in your notification bar, I would suggest using something like [GoSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en) with [WidgetLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&hl=en).

If I'm correct in your understanding, this will do what you want: Set up WidgetLocker to be your unlock screen and then place a GoSMS messaging widget on your lock screen, so you can read the messages immediately.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I hope it helps!